# Bring window on top with process ID and bring it in foreground

Tags: linux, shell

i need to bring a window in foreground by specifying its process ID. i tried to use xdotool

window_id=`xdotool search --class rdesktop`

and here i am getting the window ID of the rdesktop process eg : 41943382

and then i use xdotool activewindow 41943382 and this will bring the window to top and make it active

but here if i use more than one process of same rdesktop it is giving all of its window ID and i wan to know which process ID is associated with with window ID

i tried for xdotool search --pid 4535

but this gives an error as many of the xwindow system doesn't support it,

So is there any other way that i can get the window ID and bring it in foreground for shell . If from c also ok but i am not that much good in c so i try in shell script

Comment: Why do you ask? What is the use case? Can't you configure your particular window manager?

Comment: i am using lxde and its not related to window manager it depends on the x window application which we are going to use , i am using rdesktop and not only rdesktop most of the xwindow application does not register in metadata  its mentioned over here  http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml#window_commands

Comment: The point is that it is almost always a bad thing to do. You should not bring your own window forcibly to the top, leave that to the window manager!

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty tricky!  X is pretty abstracted from PID, because you may have clients from multiple hosts with duplicate PIDs.  I'd try using the window title and embedding identifying information in it.  rdesktop allows setting the title with the -T option.